# If I create /home as a new partition(/home is in root) and I reinstall ubuntu in root, will the /home partition gone?

Tags: partitioning

If I create `/home` as a new partition( `/home` is in `root`) and I reinstall ubuntu to `root`, will the `/home` partition gone?

Comment: After creating it, you have to move your files to the newly created partition, since from what I understand your `/home` mount point and `/` mount points are in the same hard drive partition, just repartitioning the drive won't do this part of the job. On the reinstalling part, as long as you neither perform a format on the newly created partition for the `/home` mountpoint nor remove this partition, you can reinstall your system to the partition mounted as `/` safely, just make sure to make the newly created partition mounted to `/home` during the installation.

Comment: Depends upon the install selection. If you choose "*Erase entire disk*," then your new partition will be erased along with the rest of your partitions. Other options will leave your new /home partition untouched. Remember that you must manually edit /etc/fstab to tell the newly installed system about your /home partition.

Comment: Follow this to move /home. To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving Then only use Something Else and choose/change the /home partition as /home. But DO NOT check the format box or it will be erased. You always should have good backups, so if you make a mistake or drive fails you have a way to recover.

Comment: thank you for answering my question